# LogPlot of the calculated data in For Loop in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have the following loop, for calculating a data for different values of inputs.
How I can plot the result at the end of For loop?
Its not matter if the plot is inside or outside the loop, I just want to plot the results.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
b = 10^4;
s = b/2;
tx = ((2*RandomInteger[1, s])-1) + (I*((2*RandomInteger[1, s]) - 1));
For[i = 0, i <= 20, i++, snrdb = i;
 snr = 10^(0.1*snrdb);
 sd = 1/Sqrt[snr/2];
 noise = 1/Sqrt[2]*(RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {s, 1}] + I*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {s, 1}]);
 y = tx + (sd*noise);
 rx = Flatten[Sign[Re[y]]+I*Sign[Im[y]]];
 error = Unitize[tx-rx];
 ber = Total[error]/b;
 Print["Total number of errors: ",Total[error]];
 Print["Error rate: ",N[ber]];
 ]
LogPlot[{ber, 10^-4, 10^0}, {snrdb, 0, 20}]
```

---

Thanks All,
Both techniques was useful.
Sorry b is the same as bits, I made a mistake I corrected later.
I need the continous line not discrete.
how to change the y axis to be from 10^-4 to 10^1?

Note: for the purpose of accuracy I increased b to 10^6.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
b = 10^6;
sym = b/2; tx = ((2*RandomInteger[1, sym]) - 
    1) + (I*((2*RandomInteger[1, sym]) - 1));
bervals = Reap[
    For[i = 0, i < 21, i++, snrdb = i;
     snr = 10^(0.1*snrdb);
     sd = 1/Sqrt[snr/2]; 
     noise = 1/
        Sqrt[2]*(RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {sym, 1}] + 
         I*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {sym, 1}]); 
     y = tx + (sd*noise); rx = Flatten[Sign[Re[y]] + I*Sign[Im[y]]]; 
     error = Unitize[tx - rx];
     Sow[ber = Total[error]/b];
     ]][[2, 1]];
ListLogPlot[bervals, Joined -> True]
```

Comment: You can change the y-axis using the PlotRange option

Comment: why the curve is not connected to x and y axis, I mean there is a gap , I want the curve to be reached both axises.

Comment: Hi  Timothy Wofford,

your code will result range y-axis from (1 to 1000), actually it should be from 10^-4 to 1

Comment: I got it,

it should be like this:

bert = Append[bert, Total[error]/bits];

Comment: when trying to plot I faced the following message error:
How I can fix that?

General::obspkg: PlotLegends` is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current Mathematica functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.


PlotLegends`ShadowBox is not a Graphics primitive or directive.


<< PlotLegends`;
ListLogPlot[{ber, bersim}, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {10^-4, 10^0}}, 
 Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {SNR, BER}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], 
 PlotLegend -> {Simulated, Analytical}, LegendPosition -> Automatic]

Comment: Mma has a built-in option for legends as of v9. You no longer need to load a package. Use the option PlotLegends instead of PlotLegend. If your data is just a list of single values, then ListPlot creates ordered pairs {i,bervals[[i]]}. You can try using xVals = Range[0, 20]; ListLogPlot[Transpose[{xVals, bervals}], ...];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a good application for `Reap` and `Sow`.

If you have a value you would like to accumulate in a `List` you can `Sow` the value during execution of a loop:

```
vals = Reap[
  For[i = 0, i <= 10, i++,
    Sow[i]
  ]
]
vals[[2, 1]]

(*Output*)
(*{Null, {{0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}}}*)
(*{0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}*)
```

You then capture the `Sow`-ed results with `Reap`, outside of the loop. We must use `Part` to then extract the list of relevant values from `val`. Note: This technique is very useful in many other applications other than loops. The `Reap` and `Sow` combination can be used inside almost any evaluation to collect data.

Before we can apply this technique to your code, there are a few changes that need to be made. First, the symbol `bits` is never assigned a value. This is problematic if you wish to plot the values of `ber`. Let us assume `bits` has a value of `1` for now. Second, `LogPlot` is used to plot (continuous) functions, not discrete data. Here we will want to use `ListLogPlot` instead. Making these changes and introducing `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
b = 10^4;
s = b/2;
bits=1.0;
tx = ((2*RandomInteger[1, s]) - 1) + (I*((2*RandomInteger[1, s]) - 1));
bervals = Reap[
    For[i = 0, i <= 20, i++, snrdb = i;
     snr = 10^(0.1*snrdb);
     sd = 1/Sqrt[snr/2];
     noise = 
      1/Sqrt[2]*(RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {s, 1}] + 
         I*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {s, 1}]);
     y = tx + (sd*noise);
     rx = Flatten[Sign[Re[y]] + I*Sign[Im[y]]];
     error = Unitize[tx - rx];
     Sow[ber = Total[error]/bits];
     ]][[2, 1]];
ListLogPlot[bervals]
```

Should generate a plot of the values of `ber` from inside the loop.

**EDIT**
To answer a question in the comments about using `Sow` multiple times. Here is a simple example that plots y=x^2.

```
Block[{x, y, pts},
 vals = Reap[Do[
     Sow[x = i];
     Sow[y = i^2];
     , {i, 1, 10}]][[2, 1]];
 pts = Partition[vals, 2];
 ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True]
 ]
```

Notice the use of `Partition` at the end. We wouldn't have needed to do this had we used `Sow` on the list `{x,y}` instead. I only did it this way to show the use of multiple `Sow`s.

Comment: Can I use `Reap` and `Sow` more than one time ?

Comment: @barznjy Yes, you can absolutely use `Sow` more than once. It's quite common to `Sow` multiple values and use then later. I'll edit post to give an example.

Answer (score 2):

LogPlot plots functions, ListLogPlot is used for plotting data points. You seem to be calculating a bunch of data points, and then immediately forgetting/overwriting them in the line I left below. You should add a couple of lines for remembering these values in a list.

```
bert = {};
For[i = 0, i <= 20, i++,
  ...
  ber = Total[error]/bits;
  ...
  bert = Append[bert, Total[error]];
]
ListLogPlot[bert, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, Automatic}]
```

Comment: Thanks All, Both techniques was useful. Sorry b is the same as bits, I made a mistake I corrected later. I need the continous line not discrete. how to change the y axis to be from 10^-4 to 10^1?

Note: for the purpose of accuracy I increased b to 10^6.